# Strange issue after restart of one plus two

Tags: updates, notifications, system-error, task-management, oneplus-two

I have a One Plus 2. After restarting my phone the following symptoms have occurred:

- No alerts/notification pop up on the screen for emails or anything
- I can no longer switch between apps using the right button. It just doesn't do anything, and I have to back all the way out of any individual app in order to make it work.

What I do know:

- the touch screen and all buttons work. For example pressing the right button causes it to vibrate
- No app has problems loading

As you can imagine this is amazingly frustrating. What could be wrong? Can I fix this without factory reset?

I am using Oxygen OS 3.6.1, model number A2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a Oxygen OS bug. on other hand you can have factory reset and test if it helps you or not.

Comment: I ended up doing a factory reset and it fixed it. It was the most strange error I have ever encountered, I'm not even sure how to describe it. I'm not even sure how the phone got into that condition. Thank you.